# I have been working on this code and the browser router is not working. the output is simply empty

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import About from './Container/About';
  import Profile from './Container/Profile';
 import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route} from 'react-router-dom'

 function App() {
  const [state,setState] = useState('Data')



  return (
   <div >
   <button onClick={()=>setState('About')} >About</button>
   <button onClick={()=>setState('Profile')}>Profile</button>
   {state}

   <Router>
    <Route element={<About/>} path='/about' />
 
     </Router>
   </div>
  );
  }

  export default App;
```

Why is the browser  router is not working as it is showing nothing in the output?
Why is the browser  router is not working as it is showing nothing in the output?Why is the browser  router is not working as it is showing nothing in the output?Why is the browser  router is not working as it is showing nothing in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the navigation path in order to make this work. Currently you are only updating your state, which is completely decoupled from React Router.

You can either [add a link component](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-links) or [naviagate programmatically](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#navigating-programmatically).

The following should work in your case

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
[...]
let navigate = useNavigate();
[...]
<button onClick={()=>{ setState('About'); navigate('/about'); } } >About</button>
```

Or if you don't need the state for anything other than the navigation, you can remove it and replace your buttons with React Router Link components.

Answer (score 1):

The router component maintains it's own state and routing context. You need to either use a [`Link`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link) component or the [`navigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) function to issue an imperative navigation action. Don't forget that all the `Route` components need to be wrapped by the `Routes` component so route path matching and rendering functions.

Example:

```
import About from './Container/About';
import Profile from './Container/Profile';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Router>
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
        <Link to='/about'>About</Link>
        <Link to='/profile>Profile</Link>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<h1>Home</h1>} path='/' />
          <Route element={<About />} path='/about' />
          <Route element={<Profile />} path='/profile' />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you decide to use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function in this `App` component then the `Router` will need to be higher in the ReactTree in order for the `useNavigate` hook and routing components in `App` to be able to access the routing context.